# How to create custom font at runtime using NSFont

Tags: cocoa, glyph, nsbezierpath, nsfont

I'm writing a Mac application that needs to be able to create, load, and use custom fonts at runtime using Cocoa.  I've researched the `NSFont` class thoroughly, and all I can find is API's to load existing fonts and change simple parameters (E.G. size, weight, spacing, etc.).

I need to be able to create custom glyphs from scratch while my program is running, preferably using `NSBezierPath`, combine them into an `NSFont` object or something similar, and draw text to the screen using this font.

Is this possible?  I'd imagine that font-creation applications must use this.  If it is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API in Mac OS X that will allow you to directly build a font using drawing commands.

Unfortunately, you will have to do this from scratch, building a TrueType or Postscript font file by writing the font data out into the appropriate file format and then loading the font from that file using `NSFont` or one of the other font APIs.

You might get some hints by looking at the [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net) source, although it's not a Cocoa app so may be only of limited usefulness.

Comment: Thanks!  It's nice to know what I'm dealing with.  Are there any libraries I could use to create these font files to load?  I know it's possible to draw bezier paths to a postscript file, but there must be extra data to handle.